# Inability to pass data from a tableViewController to another TableViewController that is embedded in a ViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, viewcontroller

I have been trying without any success to pass some data (`String`) from a `TableViewController` to a second `TableViewController` that is embedded in a container.

In the MainTableViewController I have the following code:

```swift
let vc = SecondTableViewController()
vc.myParm = label!.text!
let myVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
navigationController?.pushViewController(myVC, animated: true)
```

In the second table view controller (which is embedded in SecondViewController) I have a param:

`var retVal: String = ""`

This does not work, as the retVal never gets a value. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You're setting your `label.text` to your `vc` variable, but you're not using that variable anymore.

You should set the `label.text` to your `myVC` variable, because that's the one you're pushing to `navigationController`.

```swift
let myVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
myVC.myParm = label!.text!
navigationController?.pushViewController(myVC, animated: true)
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is get the parm passed to the second table view controller (VC) , which is a container in the Second View Controler (myVC).

Comment: Send the parameter to the second view controller and then in the `onViewDidLoad()` set it to your table view controller, or access the table controller across your view controller (something like `myVc.tableViewController.myParam =label!.text`).

Comment: You simply can't instantiate a `SecondTableViewController()` as you're doing, because you're not using that instance for anything.

Comment: That won't work, the SecondTableViewController loads before the SecondViewController.

Comment: That's... What? Are you sure? You're pushing a `SecondViewController` to the view stack, and never using the `SecondTableViewController`. I can't make any sense of this.

Comment: The SecondTableViewController is embedded in a container view in the SecondViewController, doesn't make sense to me either but running it in Debug shows that's the flow.

Comment: As it turns out I must have missed something in my testing earlier, because it still isn't working despite my thinking so.

Comment: What's happening (or what should happen) in your application is the next: you create the `SecondViewController` and push it to the navigation controller. Then the `SecondViewController` creates the `TableView` and its `SecondTableViewController`

Comment: It does, automatically.  As I said, its embedded via a container.

Comment: And thats why you can set up your variable where I've been saying from the beginning.

Comment: Doesn't work that way Roberto.  I thought I could instantiate the second table view controller from the second view controller but that sets the var to nil.  There is no code in the second view controller that calls the container view (second table view controller).  It all happens behind the scenes.

Comment: Still trying to find an answer to this, if one exists.